# Show DIV in other .php file only when php statement is true

Tags: php

quick question. I'm a rookie so,
when registration success I want to show `<div>` with a message(value).
So if everything is alright only then should appear on another .php file with HTML code.

I tried to return it but cannot figure out how to do it in the right way.

**NOTE:**

- Now I'm using `global` but I want to throw it out.

So I have a function in `function.php` and if...

```
function createUser(){

    global $welcome;

    $connection = connectDB();
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $passwordConfirm = $_POST["passwordConfirm"];

    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $username);
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $email);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $password);
    $passwordConfirm = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $passwordConfirm);

    if($_POST['password'] !== $_POST['passwordConfirm']){
        $error = exit("Password does not match.");
    } 

    $hashFormat = "$2y$10$";
    $salt = "iusesomecrazystrings22"; 
    $hash = $hashFormat . $salt; 

    $password = crypt($password, $hash);

    $query = "INSERT INTO users(username, email, password) VALUES ('$username', '$email', '$password')";

    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

    if(!$result){
        die("Query FAILED " . mysqli_error($connection));
    } else{
        $welcome = "Registration Success";
    }

}
```

And in other file I have something like this:

```
<?php

include 'functions.php';

global $welcome;

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    createUser();
}
?>
<div class="row justify-content-md-center">

<form action="register.php" method="post">

    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" style="text-align: center" required>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" style="text-align: center" required>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" style="text-align: center" required>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="password" name="passwordConfirm" class="form-control" placeholder="Confirm Password" style="text-align: center" required>
    </div>

    <div class="row justify-content-md-center">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="SIGN UP" class="btn btn-primary">
    </div>

    <p></p>

    <div class="row justify-content-md-center">
        <?php echo $welcome; ?>
    </div>

</form>

</div>
```

So I did it this way...

How should I `return` instead of `$welcome = "Registration Success";`, show it ONLY if `$result is true` and finally print that message in other file that contains HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can return $message from the function and receive it like this:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $message = createUser();
}
```

and modify your function createUser like this:

UPDATED

```
function createUser()
{
  // here is your function's body))))

  if ($result) {
     return "Registration Success";
  }

  die("Query FAILED " . mysqli_error($connection));
}
```

Comment: Could be further optimized by dropping the `$welcome` variable and the `else` altogether, simply returning the string directly at the end.

Comment: @Vasyl Zhuryk Yea that works, I tried something similar but wasn't working is any different if I return it in  `if` `!$result` or `$result`

Comment: You can do in different way)) I just provided short condition))

Answer (score 0):

if I understand properly:

In `createUser()`, instead of:

```
if(!$result){
    die("Query FAILED " . mysqli_error($connection));
} else{
    $welcome = "Registration Success";
}
```

Do this:

```
if(!$result){
    die("Query FAILED " . mysqli_error($connection));
}
return true;
```

And in the PHP file with the HTML do this:

```
<?php 
    include 'functions.php';

    $userCreated = false;

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $userCreated = createUser();
    }

    if ($userCreated) { ?>

        Here goes your message about successfull user creation, or you can use echo '' and you can skip PHP open close tag

    <?php } else { ?>
        <div class="row justify-content-md-center">
            <form action="register.php" method="post">
                ...
            </form>
        </div>
    <?php } 
?>
```

With this you dont need to use global, instead you use createUser function's return value, which tells you wheter it was successfull or not.